# How to adding more objects to list?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JS code:

```
menu = {
       archive: {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'},
       archive2: {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}
      };
console.log(menu);
return menu;
```

Console print all right:

```
{archive: {…}, archive2: {…}}
archive:
  name: "folder option"
  icon: "paste"

archive2:
  name: "folder option"
  icon: "paste"
```

How to I can add more items to this list? Like archive3, archive4...

If I do this:

```
 menu['archive3']="{'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}";
```

Console print with quote

```
{archive3: "{'name':'folder option', 'icon':'paste'}"}
 archive3: "{'name':'folder option', 'icon':'paste'}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```js
"{'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}"
```

This is an object

```js
{'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}
```

This will get your output right, assigning an object to `menu['archive3']` instead of a string

```js
menu['archive3'] = {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}
console.log(menu)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a string to `archive3`, when you need to assign the object without quotes:

```
menu = {
       archive: {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'},
       archive2: {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}
      };

menu['archive3'] = {'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'};

console.log(menu);
return menu;
```